# Bug in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I'm currently working on plotting simple plots using ggplot2.
The graph looks good, but there is one tiny detail I can't fix.
When you look at the legend, it says "Low n" twice. One of them should be "High n".

Here is my code:

```
  half_plot <-  ggplot() +
    ggtitle(plot_title) +
    geom_line(data = plot_dataframe_SD1, mapping = aes(x = XValues, y = YValues_SD1, color = "blue")) +
    geom_line(data = plot_dataframe_SD2, mapping = aes(x = XValues, y = YValues_SD2, color = "green")) +
    xlim(1, 2) +
    ylim(1, 7) +
    xlab("Standard Deviation") +
    ylab(AV_column_name) +
    scale_fill_identity(name = 'the fill', guide = 'legend',labels = c('m1')) +
    scale_colour_manual(name = 'Legend', 
                        values =c('blue'='blue','green'='green'),
                        labels = c(paste("Low ", Mod_column_name), paste("High ", Mod_column_name))
```

Here is the graph I get in my output:

[image]

So do you know how to fix this?
And there is one more thing that makes me curious: I can't remember that I changes anything in this code, but I know that the legend worked just fine a few days ago. I safed pictures I made wih this code and it looks alright..

Also if you have any further suggestions how to upgrade the graph, these suggestions are very welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions, it will help us if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the data. With some sample data, there are a couple ways to fix it.

Sample data

```
library(dplyr)
plot_dataframe_SD1 = data.frame(XValues=seq(1,2,by=.2)) %>%
  mutate(YValues_SD1=XValues*2)
plot_dataframe_SD2 = data.frame(XValues=seq(1,2,by=.2)) %>%
  mutate(YValues_SD2=XValues*5)
```

The simplest way to modify your code is to supply the desired color label in the aesthetic.

```
Mod_column_name = 'n'
half_plot <- ggplot() +
  # put the desired label name in the aesthetic
  # link describing the bang bang operator (!!) https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/07/bang-bang-how-to-program-with-dplyr/ geom_line(data=plot_dataframe_SD1,mapping=aes(x=XValues,y=YValues_SD1,color=!!paste('Low',Mod_column_name))) +
  geom_line(data=plot_dataframe_SD2,mapping=aes(x=XValues,y=YValues_SD2,color=!!paste('High',Mod_column_name))) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','green'),
                     labels=c(paste('Low',Mod_column_name),paste('High',Mod_column_name)))
```

A more general approach is to join the dataframes and pivot the joined df to have a column with the SD values and another to specify how to separate the colors. This makes it easier to plot without having to make multiple calls to `geom_line`.

```
# Join the dfs, pivot the SD columns longer, and make a new column with your desired labels
joined_df = plot_dataframe_SD1 %>% full_join(plot_dataframe_SD2,by='XValues') %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols=contains('YValues'),names_to='df_num',values_to='SD') %>%
  mutate(label_name=if_else(df_num == 'YValues_SD1',paste('Low',Mod_column_name),paste('High',Mod_column_name)))

# Simplified plot
ggplot(data=joined_df,aes(x=XValues,y=SD,color=label_name)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','green'),
                     labels=c(paste('Low',Mod_column_name),paste('High',Mod_column_name)))
```

[image: updated plot]